# .NET 6 Service: how to pass JSON inside JSON?

Tags: c#, json, .net-6.0

I am developing a .NET 6 web service (with Startup), one of methods is

```
public async Task<ActionResult> PutDirector([FromBody] Director director, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var title = nameof(PutDirector);
    // ....
}
```

Using Swagger I pass this JSON:

```
{
  "id": 2,
  "firstName": "Yeh",
  "lastName": "Dobedo",
  "title": "Mr",
  "birthDate": "1983-09-18",
  "address": "15 Book Street",
  "search_Permission": true
}
```

It works fine.

By design I need to store json in the field address, i.e. a client app will parse and process this sub-json.

But when I pass

```
{
  "id": 2,
  "firstName": "Yeh",
  "lastName": "Dobedo",
  "title": "Mr",
  "birthDate": "1983-09-18",
  "address": "[
      {
        'line1': '15 Book Street',
        'line2': '21 Book Street'
      }
    ],",
  "search_Permission": true
}
```

the method in the controller receives `Director` object `== null`.

I understand that JSON cannot be deserialized to object. How to pass JSON where string contains json?

Comment: This address is string for the controller object. It can contain simple string or some json which will be procesed by a client app. For example, it reads json and parse the object and displays address on a page etc.

Comment: Also, I store the address in a database as a text field (PostgreSQL)

Comment: This isn't valid JSON.  Try validating on jsonlint.com

Comment: FWIW, it's just the whitespace within the `address` string that makes this invalid JSON.

Comment: The solution is: he string "address": "...." should be in one line but not multiplelines

Comment: You're right: [json](https://www.json.org) string can't contain control characters.

Comment: Constructing JSON (or XML) by string concatenation pretty much never works. Please use proper way to generate valid JSON (like json.Stringify for JS or JSON serialization libraries of your choice for other languages) - this will avoid typos like this one in the future.

Comment: A strange  thing: the json (above) is valid in jsonlint.com but cannot be deserialized in NET method to object. It can be serialized if I write internal json to one line

Comment: [https://jsonlint.com/](https://jsonlint.com/) reports an [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54Z8g.png).

Comment: @JonathanDodds the matter is: jsonlint verified json ok, but NET cannot deserialize it to  the object. I do not see any errors because it is doing before controller method called ([FromBody]). My colleague (client app developer on Python) said me: Jsonlint verified it please correct the code

Comment: @ZedZip I took your JSON that includes address, put it in jsonlint, and it failed to pass. I linked an image. I don't know why your colleague said it verified.

Answer (score 2):

your json is not valid, if you want to treat an address object as a string, you need this json

```
{
  "id": 2,
  "firstName": "Yeh",
  "lastName": "Dobedo",
  "title": "Mr",
  "birthDate": "1983-09-18",
   "address": "[
       {
        \"line1\": \"15 Book Street\",
        \"line2\": \"21 Book Street\"
      }
    ]",
  "search_Permission": true
}
```

and if you are using newtonsoft for example you can use this code in your controller action to convert a json array to a string

```
    if (director.Address.StartsWith("["))
    {
        var address = string.Join(", ", JArray.Parse(director.Address)
         .SelectMany(i => ((JObject)i).Properties()
         .Select(p => (string)p.Value)));
        director.Address = address;
    }
```

or if you want to treat a string as an object ( remove extra "")

```
"address": [
      {
        'line1': '15 Book Street',
        'line2': '21 Book Street'
      }
    ],
```

but I would advice to create a json custom converter

Answer (score 2):

While I prefer @Serge's answer above, I wanted to point out another option for dealing with strings that are sometimes very difficult to use escape codes on.

For this to work, the client side has to understand what it is receiving. Most of the time, this means that you are writing both the service and the client code.

Difficult to escape strings can be converted to a non json strings. There are a lot of ways to do this, but a 64 bit string is pretty easy.

To encode a string named addressJson:

```
// serialize to json string stored in addressJson first

// convert to base 64 string
string jsonSafe = Convert.ToBase64String(addressJson);
```

The encoded string (your address json from above) looks like this:
`WwogICAgICAgewogICAgICAgIFwibGluZTFcIjogXCIxNSBCb29rIFN0cmVldFwiLAogICAgICAgIFwibGluZTJcIjogXCIyMSBCb29rIFN0cmVldFwiCiAgICAgIH0KICAgIF0=`

To decode on the client side:

```
// convert base 64 string back into your json
string addressJson = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(base64EncodedData));

// then send addressJson to your json deserializer to get the address object
```

Its a little more tricky to decode because the string encoding isnt assumed, but, as you can see above, it's still pretty easy.

The downside to this method is that the data in your json is not easily human readable anymore, but this may or may not matter to you.